# How to get a result of the correct class when concatenating data in R?

Tags: r, class, concatenation, rbind

I have found for `c` and `rbind` the class of the result is based on the class of the first argument. This has caused a problem for me because the presence of `NA` as the first argument coerces `Date` vectors to `numeric` vectors. Compare the result of these two `class` calls:

```
x <- Sys.Date()
y <- NA
class(c(x, y)) # "Date"
class(c(y, x)) # "numeric"
```

and likewise for `rbind`:

```
x <- data.frame(column=Sys.Date())
y <- data.frame(column=NA)
class(rbind(x, y)$column) # "Date"
class(rbind(y, x)$column) # "numeric"
```

How can I ensure the result of these concatenations is always a `Date` vector, regardless of the order of the arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coerce the first argument to your desired class:

```
c(as.Date(y), x)
c(as.Date(x), y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the method you want explicitly:

```
c.Date(y,x)
```

Comment: That's helpful for `c`, but can I do something similar for `rbind` too?

Comment: Yes, set the class of `y$column` to `Date`: `y <- data.frame(column=as.Date(NA))`